# Use controller generated by typescript in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I have an angular controller (generated by typescript):

```
class FileManagerController {
   ... 
   constructor($scope) {
      $scope.vm = this;
      ...
   }

   ...functions...
}
```

How can I use this controller in the directive?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ])
  .directive('ngFilemanager', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            require: '^ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '='
            },
            templateUrl: '/templates/filemanager.html',
            controller: ???
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the TypeScript class is not declared in a module, it would be as simple as:

```
....
controller: FileManagerController,
...
```

If you take a look at the Javascript compiled output of `FileManagerController`, you will find the function.

Comment: I copy pasted the function and got the error `FileManagerController` is not a function

Comment: Again, check the compiled TypeScript file. It does define a `FileManagerController`; if there are no modules, it will be global. You will also have to make sure that FileManagerController.js is loaded before the angular module. Make sure `FileManagerController` is loaded by calling it from the console.

Comment: my controller constructor is called twice now?